# How can i use ternary if in aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, ternary

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbIptalEt" Text="İptal Et" OnClick="lbIptalEt_Click"
                                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("OdNo") %>' OnClientClick='
                                                <%#campus.common.UniversiteAdlari.cfgUniversiteAd == campus.common.UniversiteAdlari._18Mart && !campus.Guvenlik.KullaniciRolListesi.Any(gg => gg.Id == campus.obys.ogrenci.yonetim.dersatama.idYonetici) ? "" :"return onLinkDelete(this);" %> '/>
```

This is my code. I want to manage OnClientClick , Probably i have syntax mistake.Thank you in advence.

Comment: EEP, don't paste code in comments please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
OnClientClick='<%= ((campus.common.UniversiteAdlari.cfgUniversiteAd == campus.common.UniversiteAdlari._18Mart) && !campus.Guvenlik.KullaniciRolListesi.Any(gg => gg.Id == campus.obys.ogrenci.yonetim.dersatama.idYonetici) ? "" : "return onLinkDelete(this);") %>' />
```

It should work.